# ios Mobile checkbox border bug

Tags: css, ios, svg, checkbox, mobile

I have a custom checkbox and a weird border appears around my checkbox SVGs. On the website web app, tablet, and Andriod devices it doesn't appear. Only on IOS, Has anyone come across this before and know of a fix. I have spend days looking for a fix, doing CSS hacks, googling and working with other dev's on the team and trying to find a way to inspect on mobile, but to my knowledge, not a possible thing to do on a mobile browser. Attached is the image.

[image: checkbox border bug on ios]

Comment: you mean, you want to inspect ios safari browser? if yes, it is possible to inpect

Comment: No, I need to get rid of the border bug around the SVGs on my checkbox items, only happens in IOS